# Git: accessing a coworker's branch

Tags: git

I issued the following pull to our GitHub repo...

```
L.MVC4 (master *)$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 59, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 36 (delta 29), reused 34 (delta 27)
Unpacking objects: 100% (36/36), done.
From https://github.com/CM/L.MVC4
   b002a02..82deccf  master     -> origin/master
   e690bc3..d23f567  koprod3    -> origin/koprod3
 * [new branch]      koprod4    -> origin/koprod4
Updating b002a02..82deccf
```

... and noticed 2 branches (**koprod3**, **koprod4**) from a coworker he checked in were pulled.  However, when I do a git branch I only get my branches...

```
L.MVC4 (master *)$ git branch
* master
  newbranch
  seeddata
```

So how do I gain access to his branches.  It appears they have already been pulled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are remote branches. To see them, either run `git branch -r` (only show remote branches) or `git branch -a` (show all branches).

To check them out, use `git checkout -b koprod3 origin/koprod3` (newer versions of Git also allow just `git checkout koprod3`). To create a local branch at the commit they are currently pointing to, issue the command `git branch koprod3 origin/koprod3`.

Of course, the name for your local branch can be anything and must not be identical to the remote name.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to create a local branch that tracks to his branch, like:

```
git checkout -b koprod3 origin/koprod3
```

Now you have a branch with the same name, tracking his branch on origin. The above statement actually checks that branch out, but you could use `git branch koprod3 origin/koprod3` if you just wanted to create it, and checkout later.